# Weight paint brush does nothing to my mesh

Tags: armature, weight-painting, rigify

For some reason, my weight paintbrush doesn't do anything. I am using Rigify, the free Blender addon to create a rig. I used automatic weights and then go from there. I tried to weigh paint it but even though my brush is at 100% it doesn't have any effect on any part of the mesh. It won't turn the blue to red and vice versa. I am sure it's not the addon itself as it just creates the rigs, plus it's a pretty common addon. Thanks in advance 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have 'Vertex selection masking for painting' ON.

[image]

Either turn that OFF or go to edit mode to select some vertices.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! That worked however now I can't see where the vertices are. Is there any way to maintain that view while being able to paint?

Comment: Well, you can use the Wireframe-overlay: https://i.imgur.com/Z7aDcb8.png

Comment: Or, if you want to see only the vertices, select something in edit-mode and turn the 'Vertex selection masking for painting' ON again in the Weight-painting mode